# How set backgrond imagebellow the openGL Rendering Particle?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hi I am working on OpenGL and making a wallpaper in android,I want to set simple background from my assets
   folder image image size in 480x800 & 800x480 .OpenGL Particle Render On screen as shown here:

[image: I want to set and image of jpg or png on scren rather than black screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a background image, load the image into a texture and apply the texture to a fullscreen triangle strip.  Then draw your particles on top of the textured triangle strip.

```
// During initialization:
int width = ..., height = ...;
void *data = ...;
GLuint tex;

glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height,
             0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Drawing the textured primitive will be different depending on OpenGL version
```

You are on your own when it comes to loading the image into memory.  OpenGL does not decode image formats.  (On Windows you can use WIC, on Mac OS X / iOS you can use Quartz, on Linux/etc. you can use LibPNG/LibJPEG/etc.)